# Oauth2 with Spring-Security: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2TokenGranter': Cannot create inner bean of type ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter

Tags: java, exception, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am new is Oauth and Spring-Security. I trying to integrate oauth with Spring Security using client detail and token details from database. I am using the latest depenecies for `spring-security` and `spring-security-oauth`. Following is my dependencies:

```
<!-- Spring Security Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END of Core Spring and Spring Web Dependencies -->
```

The versions are bellow.

```
<spring-security-oauth2>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2>
<spring.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
```

This is my maven multi-module project. So the all dependency manage in parent module.

Following is my `spring-security-config.xml` with oauth2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd ">

<!-- Create client details bean for manage client details from database -->
<!-- The JdbcClientDetailsService provide default implementation for fetching 
    the data from oauth_client_details table Other wise we need to create our 
    custom class that Implement ClientDetailsService Interface and override its 
    loadClientByClientId method -->
<bean id="clientDetails"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.JdbcClientDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Configure Authentication manager -->
<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg name="strength" value="11" />
</bean>

<!-- This class is the custom implementation of UserDetailSerive Interface 
    that provide by the spring, which we Need to implement and override its method. 
    But for Oauth spring provide us ClientDetailsUserDetailsService, which already 
    implement UserDetailSerive Interface and override its method. -->
<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"></property>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="oauthDaoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"> 
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" /> <property name="userDetailsService" 
    ref="clientDetailsUserService" /> </bean> -->

<sec:authentication-manager id="oauthAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<!-- Oauth Token Service Using Database -->
<!-- The JdbcTokenStore class provide the default implementation from access 
    the token from database. If we want to customize the JDBC implementation 
    we need to implement TokenStore interface and overrider its methods -->
<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- This the service class which is used to access the function of JdbcTokenStore 
    class. This is like MVC structure JdbcTokenStore is Dao layer and DefaultTokenServices 
    is service layer -->
<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<!-- A user approval handler that remembers approval decisions by consulting 
    existing tokens -->
<bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
</bean>

<!-- Authorization Server Configuration of the server is used to provide 
    implementations of the client details service and token services and to enable 
    or disable certain aspects of the mechanism globally. -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">

    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>
-----------------------------
```

When trying to deploy the application, the follwing stacktrace will pring ion console:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oauth2TokenGranter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1a0bdce' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter] while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1a0bdce': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5170)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
-------------------------------------
```

When, i comment the `<oauth:authorization-server` configuration from the `spring-security-oauth.xml`configuration file, there is no error, but when we un-comment, the exception will throw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem, accordingto the error and spring-security api docs `ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` class need the `authenticationManager` for creating an object. so just replace :

```
<oauth:authorization-server
client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
 ------------------
<oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

With :

```
<oauth:authorization-server
client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
 ------------------
<oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"/>
</oauth:authorization-server>
```